# Shortest code to generate a full mesh of elements

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, graph, combinatorics

I am trying to find the shortest code that generates a full mesh of the elements fed into it in graphviz format
e.g. the full mesh of [0, 1, 2] is:

- `2 -> 0`
- `2 -> 1`
- `1 -> 0`

I have the code below and I think there might be a way to combine the if and for loops, and avoid needing to directly create the empty string

```py
def graph(l):
    if not l:
        return ""
    i = l.pop()
    out = ""
    for z in l:
        out += "  {}->{}\n".format(i, z)
    return out + graph(l)
print graph(range(3))
```

Comment: Did you hear about [meshpy](https://documen.tician.de/meshpy/) ? Does it help you ?

Comment: I'm not trying to generate a mesh in the model sense but a mesh in the network topology sense where every node is connected to every other node, mostly I want to see how mutch smaller I can make the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get it correctly, the shortest way that I can think of is by using `itertools.combinations`. Basically, you want all unique combinations, so:

```
from itertools import combinations

def mesh(L):
    return ["->".join(map(str, comb)) for comb in combinations(L, 2)]
```

Which will return:

```
['1->2', '1->3', '2->3']
```

For: `mesh([1, 2, 3])`

If you then want to print them as above, just:

```
for x in mesh([1, 2, 3]):
    print(x)
```